# AngularJS filter to compare day with ID - ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a motivational quote of the day with Angular JS, PHP/MYSQL.
I have 31 quotes in the DB, for each days of the month. 
How would I use ng-show or ng-hide and compare it with Today's day & post ID to show the post that match? So for instance today we are the 3rd, so my script would call post ID 3.

This is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('quotesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.quotes = data;
  });

});
```

UPDATE!

Thank you Peter, I'm almost sooo close to get this working! I did a var_dump($arr);
[image]

Anyone who is really good at PHP, my apologies for the rough coding.
Her is my getQuotes.php PHP file:

```
<?php
include('../includes/config.php');

$query="select id,quote from quotes order by id desc";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}
unset($arr[0]);

$numItems = count($arr);
$i = 0;

foreach($arr as $key => $value ){
    if(++$i === $numItems) {
        echo "$key: '$value[quote]' ";
      }else{
    echo "$key: '$value[quote]', ";
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
//var_dump($arr);

# JSON-encode the response
//$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
//echo $json_response;


?>
```

My app.js file is:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
  $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.quotes = data;
  });
   $scope.dayNumber = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'd');
   console.log($http);
});
```

And all I get is:

```
3 
'
```

instead of getting:

```
3
its the third day of the month
```

*** UPDATE 2 ****

In app.js, the following function is erroring out:

```
$timeout(function() {
          // Parse the JSON
          $scope.quotes = JSON.parse(data);
      })
```

error says:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
```

When I change the function to stringify:

```
$timeout(function() {
          var jsonString = JSON.stringify( data );

          $scope.quotes = jsonString;
          console.log($scope.quotes);
      })
```

The error disapear but the output is still incorrect, as when I do  console.log($scope.quotes); I get:

```
{"1":{"id":"3","quote":"its the third day of the month"},"2":{"id":"2","quote":"its the second day of the month"},"3":{"id":"1","quote":"its the first day of the month"}}
```

**** UPDATE 2 ********

I updated function and error has disappeared as suggested by Peter so app.js looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http, $timeout) {
  $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){
    //$scope.quotes = data;

// This triggers a 'digest', to tell the views to update.
      $timeout(function() {
          console.log(data);
        $scope.quotes = data;
      })

  });
   $scope.dayNumber = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'd');
});
```

The output, however, looks like json, please see below screenshot:
[image]

```
3 
{"id":"1","quote":"its the first day of the month"}
```

This is a closeup from the above screenshot, it should be easier to read:
[image]

Comment: I read you question 2 different ways. Are you trying to pass a parameter into the `.post()` request so it only returns the quote from the current day? Or do you have all the quotes for the month on the page and only want to show the current day's quote?

Comment: Thanks, I am returning 1 post on the page which should match the day. It is outputing the whole data object at the moment...From what Peter is trying to explain me, it has something to do with the parsing to json but still looking for a solution

Comment: You're so close! Leave exactly as it was but change the template from {{quotes[dayNumber]}} to {{quotes[dayNumber]['quote']}}

Comment: Peter, you are amazing. This works!! You've got a twitter fan. Thanks v much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angularJS built in date filter. Here is a working example that will make things easy:

http://plnkr.co/edit/X1k3nQdYi9K1zfP2yfR6?p=preview

Code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>require moment</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TimeCtrl">
    <p>
      {{dayNumber}}
      <br />{{quotes[dayNumber]['quote']}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module("app", [])
      .controller("TimeCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.quotes = {
          1: 'Its the first of the month',
          2: 'Its the second of the month',
          3: 'Its the third of the month',
          4: 'Its the fourth of the month',
          5: 'Its the fifth of the month',
          6: 'Its the sixth of the month'
        }
        $scope.dayNumber = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'd');
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Output is:

```
4 
Its the fourth of the month
```

===========

After adding PHP code and AngularJS:

You should go back to using json_encode, don't try to do it yourself. Just remember to decode it in the javascript:

```
/*
foreach($arr as $key => $value ){
    if(++$i === $numItems) {
        echo "$key: '$value[quote]' ";
      }else{
    echo "$key: '$value[quote]', ";
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
*/
//var_dump($arr);

# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

And don't forget to decode the JSON from a string into a javascript object after it gets retrieved:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http, $timeout) {
  $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){
      // This triggers a 'digest', to tell the views to update.
      $timeout(function() {
          // Parse the JSON
          $scope.quotes = JSON.parse(data);
      })
  });
  $scope.dayNumber = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'd');

   // Also, this won't do anything sensible
   console.log($http);
});
```

Finally, if the result is bound to a view and you need to see it update, you should wrap your changes in a $timeout or call $rootScope.$apply, see above.

Comment: Thanks! The php file output: 1: 'its the third day of the month', 2: 'its the second day of the month', 3: 'its the first day of the month' but all I get is day 3 (I'm in Australia) and ', a single apostrophe, almost like the data is not feeding correctly? So what i get is:
3
'

Comment: Can you show exactly what the php file output is? Is it JSON? Is it an array on an object? You may need to decode it. Finally, you may also need to call $rootScope.$apply if it's asnychronous (run in an AJAX call)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have updated my post, thank you very much for the genuine help!

Comment: Hello, no problem, just upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem :). I updated my answer, I hope that gets you the result you want.

Comment: I get an angular error with: $scope.quotes = JSON.parse(data);
the error is:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: Try putting console.log(data); before the JSON.parse line so we can see what's coming in, or look in the browser logs.

Comment: Oh, I don't think you need to decode it in the javascript, it looks like it was automaticaly decoded by angular. Try taking out the parseJOSN line and just having it equal data and see what happens.

Comment: One final thing to be careful about is that the type you are indexing the quotes array with is the same as the one returned from the date filter. You can just do $scope.date.toString() to get the string value instead of the integer.